# php replace complete numbers

Tags: php, str-replace

Hi hope somebody can help me, I have the following code but I send $data = 11, it sends me a 1010 instead of 100, is replacing the '1' two times, does anybody know how to fix this? thanks

```
$search = ['1','2','3','11','12','13'];
$replace = ['10','25','50','100','250','500'];
return str_replace($search, $replace, $data);
```

Comment: str_replace, runs in the order your array is so if you have a string like `100` the `1` is found first and replaced with `10` making `1000` then if anything else matches it's replaced as well, there is no start end anchors in str_repllace.  So `11`, matches `1` 2x and becomes `1010`

Comment: If you sole purpose is to return a *corresponding* value, then why don't you create an associative array like this `$searchArr = [1 => 10, 2 => 25, 3 => 50, 11 => 100, ...];` and return the associated element like this `return $searchArr[$data];`?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul - my thoughts exactly.  Then it's trivial to pull them out.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix GMTA. :-)

Comment: Hi Rajdeep Paul, thanks it worked, if you answer I will declare you the winner,  Rizier123 I don't see how this questions is an exact duplicate

Comment: This was my go at it `$search = ['13'=>'500','12'=>'250','11'=>'100','3'=>'50','2'=>'25','1'=>'10'];`  I would use string keys, it protects them against sorting and other array functions, that re-index the array ...  but that is just how I roll.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the reverse order and use a foreach with a $count check like the following:

```
$search = ['13','12','11','3','2','1'];
$replace = ['500', '250', '100','50','25','10'];
for($i=0, $count=0; $i<count($search); $i++) {
    $data = str_replace($search[$i], $replace[$i], $data, $count);
    if ($count) {
       return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain why....  I know why..  Probably still have an issue with the 1, if using a difference number,  such as 131, you get 50010.

Comment: You will also run into trouble with this and already replaced numbers being replaced again. `11` replacing to `100` would later have `1` replaced to `10` making it finally `1000`

Comment: thanks jakub wrona, how can I limit to only once? Jonathan Kuhn is right it gave me 1000